# Roots of a Family of Polynomials with some Pattern

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, polynomials, roots, roots-of-unity

For any integer $q>5$ such that $5\nmid q$, set $f_q(x)=x^q-20x^5-1$. All the roots of this polynomial are simple and so it has $q$ distinct roots $\alpha_1,\ldots, \alpha_q$.

By using *Mathematica* software I observed the following pattern. In fact, one can split
$$
\{\alpha_1,\ldots, \alpha_q\}=\{\beta_1,\ldots, \beta_{q-5}\}\cup \{\gamma_1,\ldots, \gamma_5\}
$$
such that, $|\beta_i|$ tends to $1$ as $q\to \infty$ (for all $i\in [1,q-5]$) and $|\gamma_j|$ tends to the $j$-th fifth root of $1/20$, as $q\to \infty$ (for all $j\in [1,5]$).

In other words, the set $\{\gamma_1,\ldots, \gamma_5\}$ "tends" to the vertexes of a regular pentagon (as $q$ tends to infinity).

Someone could please give me some suggestion to deal with that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your message but I didn't understand. First, how to make "for high values of $q$" precise and secondly, the roots of $x^5(x^{k-5}-1)$ are $0$ and $k-5$ roots of unity. Could you please clarify it? Thanks

Comment: @reuns Thanks! And how to prove that the other roots tend to the boundary of the unit circle?

Answer (score 2):

$f_q\to -20x^5-1$ uniformly on $|x|< 1-\epsilon$ (which contains the 5 roots of $-20x^5-1$) so for $q$ large enough, $f_q$ has $5$ roots on $|x|< 1-\epsilon$ and they converge to those of $-20x^5-1$.

For $q$ large enough $f_q$ has no roots on $|q|> 1+\epsilon$.

So (for $q$ large enough) the $q-5$ remaining roots of $f_q$ lie on the annulus $1-\epsilon\le|x|\le 1+\epsilon$.

Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary it means that the absolute value of the remaining roots $\to 1$.

Obviously you can replace $f_q$ by $x^q+g$ with $g$ any polynomial whose roots lie on the unit disk, the result will be the same.

Comment: Thanks! But I didn't understand why  "(for $q$ large enough) the $q-5$ remaining roots of $f_q$ lie on the annulus $1-\epsilon\le|x|\le 1+\epsilon$." That is, Why some of other $q-5$ roots can not lie in the ball $B(0,1-\epsilon)$?

Comment: Usually we prove with some complex analysis theorems (the argument principle) that $f_q$ has 5 roots on $|x|< 1-\epsilon$. Without complex analysis, you can say that $f_q'\to g'(x)=(-20x^5-1)'$ uniformly, so on a small disk around a root $b_j$ of $g$ you'll have that $\Re(f_q'(x)/g'(b))> 0$ for $q$ large enough, which forbids more than one root near $b_j$. On $|x[<1-\epsilon$ away from the roots $b_j$ you know that $|g|$ is bounded below, for $q$ large enough $|f_q|$ will be bounded below as well.

Comment: Yes, I think you are saying about Rouché's theorem to ensure that there exists only $5$ roots inside $B(0,1-\epsilon)$, for any $\epsilon$ and $q$ large enough. Thanks!